# How to trigger a function after return statement in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have 2 functions.

1st function stores the data received in a list and 2nd function writes the data into a csv file.

I'm using Flask. Whenever a web service has been called it will store the data and send response to it, as soon as it sends response it triggers the 2nd function.

**My Code**:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, session
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

arr = []

@app.route("/test", methods=['GET','POST'])
def check():
    arr.append(request.form['a'])
    arr.append(request.form['b'])
    res = {'Status': True}
    return json.dumps(res)

def trigger():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': arr})
    df.to_csv("docs/xyz.csv", index=False)
    return
```

Obviously the 2nd function is not called.

Is there a way to achieve this?

*P.S: My real life problem is different where `trigger` function is time consuming and I don't want user to wait for it to finish execution.*

Comment: I had similar problem in past, I used celery to push the function to task queue and returned success. you can also check async implementation with aiohttp. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430465/creating-non-blocking-restful-service-using-aiohttp

Comment: What was the end solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to have a background thread that will watch a queue. You put your csv data in the queue and the background thread will consume it. You can start such a thread before first request:

```
import threading
from multiprocessing import Queue

class CSVWriterThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.input_queue = Queue()

    def send(self, item):
        self.input_queue.put(item)

    def close(self):
        self.input_queue.put(None)
        self.input_queue.join()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            csv_array = self.input_queue.get()
            if csv_array is None:
                break

            # Do something here ...
            df = pd.DataFrame({'x': csv_array})
            df.to_csv("docs/xyz.csv", index=False)


            self.input_queue.task_done()
            time.sleep(1)
        # Done
        self.input_queue.task_done()
        return

@app.before_first_request
def activate_job_monitor():
    thread = CSVWriterThread()
    app.csvwriter = thread
    thread.start()
```

And in your code put the message in the queue before returning:

```
@app.route("/test", methods=['GET','POST'])
def check():
    arr.append(request.form['a'])
    arr.append(request.form['b'])
    res = {'Status': True}
    app.csvwriter.send(arr)
    return json.dumps(res)
```

Comment: and `Queue` is in `multiprocessing` module now.

Comment: One more thing, how can I pass multiple params to `app.csvwriter.send(arr)`. ?Suppose I have to send one more array called `j = [1,2]`  How to read it in `run` function?

Comment: Pass and get them as a tuple: ```app.csvwriter.send((first_arg, second_arg))``` and then ```first_arg, second_arg, = self.input_queue.get()```

Answer (score 1):

Im actually working on another interesting case on my side where i pass the work off to a python worker that sends the job to a redis queue. There are some great blogs using redis with Flask , you basically need to ensure redis is running (able to connect on port 6379)

The worker would look something like this:

```
import os

import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['default']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(list(map(Queue, listen)))
        worker.work()
```

In my example I have a function that queries a database for usage and since it might be a lengthy process i pass it off to the worker (running as a seperate script)

```
def post(self):

    data = Task.parser.parse_args()

    job = q.enqueue_call(
        func=migrate_usage, args=(my_args),
        result_ttl=5000
    )
    print("Job ID is: {}".format(job.get_id()))
    job_key = job.get_id()

    print(str(Job.fetch(job_key, connection=conn).result))

    if job:
        return {"message": "Job : {} added to queue".format(job_key)}, 201
```

Credit due to the following article:

https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-implementing-a-redis-task-queue/#install-requirements

Comment: sounds interesting...looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

*P.S: My real life problem is different where trigger function is time consuming and I don't want user to wait for it to finish execution.*

Consider using [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/) which is made for the very problem you're trying to solve. From docs:

> Celery is a simple, flexible, and reliable distributed system to process vast amounts of messages, while providing operations with the tools required to maintain such a system.

I recommend you integrate celery with your flask app as described [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/celery/). your `trigger` method would then become a straightforward celery task that you can execute without having to worry about long response time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use streaming. See next example:

```
import time
from flask import Flask, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return '''<div>start</div>
    <script>
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/test', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = '' + this.readyState + ':' + this.responseText;
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        };
        xhr.send();
    </script>
    '''

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    def generate():
        app.logger.info('request started')
        for i in range(5):
            time.sleep(1)
            yield str(i)
        app.logger.info('request finished')
        yield ''
    return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/plain')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 8080, True)
```

All magic in this example in genarator where you can start response data, after do some staff and yield empty data to end your stream.

For details look at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/streaming/.

Answer (score 0):

You can defer route specific actions with limited context by combining after_this_request and response.call_on_close.  Note that request and response context won't be available but the route function context remains available.  So you'll need to copy any request/response data you'll need into local variables for deferred access.

I moved your array to a local var to show how the function context is preserved.  You could change your csv write function to an append so you're not pushing data endlessly into memory.

```
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, session
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test", methods=['GET','POST'])
def check():
    arr = []
    arr.append(request.form['a'])
    arr.append(request.form['b'])
    res = {'Status': True}

    @flask.after_this_request
    def add_close_action(response):
        @response.call_on_close
        def process_after_request():
            df = pd.DataFrame({'x': arr})
            df.to_csv("docs/xyz.csv", index=False)
        return response
    return json.dumps(res)
```